# Sort an array alphabetically in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

How to sort object by its value alphabetical order not by key? Here is object

```
{
1: "Arabic"
2: "Bulgarian"
3: "Catalan"
4: "Chinese"
5: "Croatian"
6: "Czech"
7: "Danish"
8: "Dutch"
9: "English"
10: "Estonian"
11: "Finnish"
12: "French"
13: "German"
14: "Greek"
15: "Hebrew"
16: "Hungarian"
17: "Icelandic"
18: "Indonesian"
19: "Italian"
20: "Japanese"
21: "Korean"
22: "Latvian"
23: "Lithuanian"
24: "Norwegian"
25: "Polish"
26: "Portuguese"
27: "Romanian"
28: "Russian"
29: "Serbian"
30: "Slovak"
31: "Slovenian"
32: "Spanish"
33: "Swedish"
34: "Turkish"
35: "Afrikaans"
}
```

and desired output by alphabetical order

{
35: "Afrikaans"
1: "Arabic"
2: "Bulgarian"
3: "Catalan"
4: "Chinese"
5: "Croatian"
6: "Czech"
7: "Danish"
8: "Dutch"
9: "English"
10: "Estonian"
11: "Finnish"
12: "French"
13: "German"
14: "Greek"
15: "Hebrew"
16: "Hungarian"
17: "Icelandic"
18: "Indonesian"
19: "Italian"
20: "Japanese"
21: "Korean"
22: "Latvian"
23: "Lithuanian"
24: "Norwegian"
25: "Polish"
26: "Portuguese"
27: "Romanian"
28: "Russian"
29: "Serbian"
30: "Slovak"
31: "Slovenian"
32: "Spanish"
33: "Swedish"
34: "Turkish"
}

Comment: There's no array here, just an object. What's the expected output?

Comment: My expected output is {35: "Afrikaans",1: "Arabic" 2: "Bulgarian" 3: "Catalan" 4: "Chinese" 5: "Croatian" 6: "Czech" 7: "Danish" 8: "Dutch" 9: "English" 10: "Estonian" 11: "Finnish" 12: "French" 13: "German" 14: "Greek" 15: "Hebrew" 16: "Hungarian" 17: "Icelandic" 18: "Indonesian" 19: "Italian" 20: "Japanese" 21: "Korean" 22: "Latvian" 23: "Lithuanian" 24: "Norwegian" 25: "Polish" 26: "Portuguese" 27: "Romanian" 28: "Russian" 29: "Serbian" 30: "Slovak" 31: "Slovenian" 32: "Spanish" 33: "Swedish" 34: "Turkish"}

Comment: Could you update your expected result on your question?

Comment: You can't really sort object keys. Perhaps you meant to create an array?

Comment: I would like to know the use case.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackOverflow, this question would be on [Javascript section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

```
const obj = {1: "Arabic", ... }
```

For your question, if you need an Array sorted:

```
const sorted = Object.values(obj).sort();
```

If you need an object, with sorted array:

```
const newObj = {}
sorted.forEach((name, index) => newObj[index] = name)
```

Comment: You've just recreated the same object. You can't really sort object keys. That's what arrays are for

Comment: I created new object with sorted values. :/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's an object instead of an array of your given input. We could not sort on an object but we could determine the iteration order over an object by overriding the Iterator interface as below:

```js
const myObj = {
  1: "Arabic",
  2: "Bulgarian",
  3: "Catalan",
  4: "Chinese",
  5: "Croatian",
  6: "Czech",
  7: "Danish",
  8: "Dutch",
  9: "English",
  10: "Estonian",
  11: "Finnish",
  12: "French",
  13: "German",
  14: "Greek",
  15: "Hebrew",
  16: "Hungarian",
  17: "Icelandic",
  18: "Indonesian",
  19: "Italian",
  20: "Japanese",
  21: "Korean",
  22: "Latvian",
  23: "Lithuanian",
  24: "Norwegian",
  25: "Polish",
  26: "Portuguese",
  27: "Romanian",
  28: "Russian",
  29: "Serbian",
  30: "Slovak",
  31: "Slovenian",
  32: "Spanish",
  33: "Swedish",
  34: "Turkish",
  35: "Afrikaans",
};

myObj[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  const entries = Object.entries(this).sort((a, b) => a[1].localeCompare(b[1]));

  for (const [key, value] of entries) {
    // you could determine what structure looks like here
    yield { [key]: value };
  }
};

for (const x of myObj) {
  console.log(x);
}
```